# Textbox isn't highlighting 'red' on validation error

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml

I am binding a TextBox control to an entity called Address, which has a sub-property AddressLines. Internal validation logic has ValidationErrors for AddressLines property, but it doesn't reflect 'visually' on the control via a Red border.

```
    <TextBox  Text="{Binding Path=Address.AddressLines, 
                             Mode=TwoWay,
                             UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                             NotifyOnValidationError=True}" 

              ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                                Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
```

If I am not wrong, it happens because the Entity `Address` itself isn't null and the property `AddressLines` is. If this is the case, how to notify the control for validation errors in case of Master-Detail errors?

Comment: Perhaps extend your Address / AddressLines with IDataErrorInfo? I'm happy to provide a sample if you want.

Comment: @Nick: Oh Yes please, if you have a link.

Answer (score 1):

The best bet is to use the IDataErrorInfo interface to customise how your objects control their validation state.

Take a look at the article [here](http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/wpf-validation-made-easy-with-idataerrorinfo/), it gives a great example. If you want a sample relevant to your code, please provide a piece of your Address etc. class, and I'll see what I can do!

Comment: Thank you. I will check it out and get back to you.